# Trouble with making dot plot of GO terms in R studio

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plot

My aim is to visualize gene ontology terms in R studio, so I'm looking for a good way to make a dot plot with my own GO terms got from PANTHER. I found a tutorial using ggplot, but unfortunateley I’m stucked running it succesfully, the plotting code gives this message at the end : Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale.
I am a bit confused why this error keeps popping out...
My data looks like this:

```
GO_biological_process, Gene_number, Fold_enrichment, FDR

GO0021782, 14, 3.17, 1.10E-02

GO0022610, 78, 2.07, 1.11E-06

GO0032103, 38, 1.92, 1.20E-02

...
```

Does anyone have any advice on how to deal with the problem or know any good tutorials?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Regards,
Fanni

---

the code I used:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = GO_biological_process, y = Fold_enrichment)) + 
geom_hline(yintercept = 1, linetype="dashed",
color = "azure4", size=.5)+
geom_point(data = data, aes(x=GO_biological_process, y=Fold_enrichment,size = Gene_number, color = '|log10 (FDR)|'), alpha=.7)+
scale_x_discrete(limits= data$GO_biological_process)+
scale_color_gradient(low = "green", high = "red", limits=c(0, NA))+
coord_flip()+
theme_bw()+
theme(axis.ticks.length=unit(-0.1, "cm"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(margin=margin(5,5,0,5,"pt")),
    axis.text.y = element_text(margin=margin(5,5,5,5,"pt")),
    axis.text = element_text(color = "black"),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
legend.title.align = 0.5)+ 
xlab("GO biological processes")+ 
ylab("Fold enrichment") + 
labs(color="log10(FDR)", size="Number\nof genes")+ 
guides(y= guide_legend(order=2), 
     color = guide_colourbar(order=1))
```

Comment: The problem comes from `color = '|log10 (FDR)|'` which is not a right input

Comment: OP, we would need to see some of your dataset to be able to help you fully, but my suspicion is that this particular piece of your code is the issue: `color = '|log10 (FDR)|'`.  Are you looking to take the absolute value of a column named "`log10 (FDR)`"?  Since this name has a space in it, you have to reference it within the back tick marks `\`` (not single quotation `'`).  If you want absolute value, you can use `abs()` to do that on the fly.  So, might look a bit like this:  `color = abs(\`X\`)`, where `X` is your column name in-between backticks.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comments! Indeed, the problem was the incorrect code of color, after using abs() function I run it successfully. Thx!!!